# MySQL executes sleep command when UPDATE query is used

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, discord.py

I have created a discord bot that interacts with a mysql database but when you run a command that uses the UPDATE query it doesnt execute the update query but executes sleep , meaning the data in the DB isnt chnaged.

(from comment)

```
@client.command()   
async def SetJob(ctx, uid: str, rank: str):
    disout = exec("UPDATE users SET 'job'='{0}' WHERE identifier='{1}'".format(rank,uid))
    if ctx.message.author == client.user:
        return
    if ctx.message.author.id not in whitelisted:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="You are not authorized to use this bot", description='Please contact Not Soviet Bear to add you to the whitelisted members list', color=discord.Color.red()))
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Job Change", description="Job changed to '{0}' for Identifier'{1}'".format(rank,uid), color=discord.Color.blue()))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail.  It is highly unlikely that MySQL would substitute SLEEP for an UPDATE command. Please show the code in question so we can help you.

Comment: Here is the code in question , Ive had to link it on a paste bin as its too long to add to the comment
https://pastebin.com/b4hUNSJq

As for editing the question, that is the best I can explain it as I dont know whats causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "bot" is periodically doing `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?  Well, the `UPDATE` probably finished so fast that it did not see the query.

The `Sleep` says that the connection is still sitting there, but doing nothing.  (There is no "sleep command"; "Sleep" indicates that no query is running at the instant.)

So, perhaps the question is "why did my update not do anything?".  In order to debug that (or get help from us),

- Check for errors after running the update.  (You should always do this.)
- Figure out the exact text of the generated SQL.  (Sometimes there is an obvious syntax error or failure to escape, say, quotes.)

Comment: Its not running the update query, the data in the db stays the same and doesnt change

Comment: @DimitriSlavoski - Please rule out syntax errors, data errors, etc before claiming that it is "not running the update query". simply because the table is unchanged.